# Error in execution of Maven project in Jenkins

Tags: maven, unix, jenkins

I am getting below errors while executing maven job from Jenkins.I have installed the maven software in Linux and provided the path in global tool configuration section of Jenkins.Error is saying pom.xml file is missing.but I am not getting no clue how to fix this issue.

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JOBS/maventest). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Also, the  output for mvn --version

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /home/test/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/jdk1.8.0_131/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

value I have set in /etc/profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_131
export M2_HOME=/home/test/apache-maven-3.6.3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2:$PATH
```

Please help in fixing this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most important hint: `Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.`

Comment: sorry I have little knowledge about the above issue.Do I need to run any command to generate pom.xml file OR do I need to create pom.xml  file in any directory ?? Please help

Comment: Yes, You need to create pom.xml in your base directory or root level and then run the maven goals.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot